# Using overlays in itemize with nested items for stepwise alerts

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays

I am wondering if there is a default (or manual) overlay specification that produces the following -

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<alerted on slides 1-2> Parent 1
\begin{itemize}
\item<alerted on slide 1 only> 1.1
\item<alerted on slide 2 only> 1.2
\end{itemize}
\item<alerted on slides 3-4> Parent 2
\begin{itemize}
\item<alerted on slide 3 only> 2.1
\item<alerted on slide 4 only> 2.2
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

The gist is that all items and subitems are visible, but the slides proceed stepwise alerting each subitem in turn, and the parent item remains alerted while focus is on any child subitem of that parent. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use `[<alert@+>]` for the inner `itemize` and something of the form `\alert<m-n>` for the `\item`s of the outer `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item\alert<1-3>{Parent 1}
\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
\item1.1
\item1.2
\item1.3
\end{itemize}
\item\alert<4-5>{Parent 2}
\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
\item2.1
\item2.2
\end{itemize}
\item\alert<6-10>{Parent 3}
\begin{itemize}[<alert@+>]
\item3.1
\item3.2
\item3.3
\item3.4
\item3.5
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I used essentially the same form, but instead of \alert explicitly, I used \item<alert@x>, which was not working. I assume that must have been setting a default, inherited by the nested items?

Comment: @mlh3789 to achive the desired effect, one could've used `\item\action<alert@1-2>{Parent 1}` instead, but not just `<\alert@1-2>` without \action.

Comment: A side effect of the two syntaxes `\item<alert@1>` versus `\item\action<alert@1>` appears to be the bullets are not alerted in the second method. So, how about the above question with a default overlay spec (ie completely specified at the `\begin{itemize}` )?

Comment: @mlh3789 please see my updated answer with an automated possibility for the inner `itemize`.

Comment: That is indeed the method I ended up using, though not totally automated it is most likely the most practical and intuitive.