# Alert items in a block that is overlayed

Tags: beamer

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}{First}
    block
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{Second}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So far, so simple. Now, let us overlay the blocks:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}<1->{First}
    block
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<2->{Second}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Still fine and simple. Now, what I want is to overlay the items in the second block and alert them.

```
 \documentclass{beamer}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Test}
   \begin{block}<1->{First}
     block
   \end{block}
   \begin{block}<2->{Second}
     \begin{itemize}
     \item\alert<+(1)> {Foo}
     \item\alert<+(1)> {Bar}
     \end{itemize}
   \end{block}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Is the a way to shorten the overlaying specifications? I tried many variant of `<+-| @alert+>` but nothing worked. I could make the code from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154448/412) to work, but it is still not flexible. So my question is: Is there a nicer and more flexible and generic way to achieve this kind of overlyaing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With 3 slides

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}<+->{First}
    block
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<+->{Second}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<.-|alert@.> Foo
    \item<+-|alert@+> Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A factorized version:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}<+->{First}
    block
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<+->{Second}
    \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
    \item<.-|alert@.> Foo
    \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### With 4 slides

[image]

Version with a syntax similar as the first example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}<+->{First}
    block
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<+->{Second}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item<+-|alert@+> Foo
    \item<+-|alert@+> Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Version with a factorized syntax:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{block}<+->{First}
    block
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}<+->{Second}
    \begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]
    \item Foo
    \item Bar
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems like the second alternative can be compactified further: In the second block the overlaying specification of the items can be removed, and instead the `itemize` block should be: `\begin{itemize}[<+-|alert@+>]`. Is there something similar for the first case?

Comment: @Dror Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my answer.

Comment: Is it correct that there's no way to factorize the first case?

Comment: @Dror In the first case, you can factorize `<+-|alert@+>` (useful if you have three or more items) but the first item still needs its special overlaying specification (`<.-|alert@.>`).

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for.  I create a macro (not an environment!) called `\makealerts{}` to which you pass the groups that are to be successively highlighted with an alert.

EDITED to be forgiving of an extra space at the end of the `\makealerts` argument list (in this MWE, of the line feed that follows `{Bar none}`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{index}
\newcommand\makealerts[1]{\itemize\relax
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\csname arg\romannumeral\narg\endcsname}{}}%
    {\def\maxnarg{\numexpr\narg-1\relax}}{\def\maxnarg{\narg}}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\theindex<\maxnarg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \item\alert<+(1)> {\csname arg\romannumeral\theindex\endcsname}%
  }%
  \enditemize%
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Test}
   \begin{block}<1->{First}
     block
   \end{block}
   \begin{block}<2->{Second}
     \makealerts{%
       {Foo of many words}
       {Bar none}
     }
   \end{block}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]